# How to set theme for a RatingBar programmatically in Android

Tags: android, themes

I had a `RatingBar` like this in my layout file:

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleIndicator"
    android:theme="@style/MyRatingBar"
    ... />
```

It worked as I expected and now I need to create it dynamically inside my java code and I set style for it like this:

```
RatingBar ratingBar = new RatingBar(getApplicationContext(), null, android.R.attr.ratingBarStyleIndicator);
```

But I do not know how to set theme `MyRatingBar` for that.

Comment: how do you want to change that? there is any theme changing option in your app?

Comment: H do not know what you means, I just wanna do what I have done in xml, in java

Answer (score 0):

there the solution use **AppCompatRatingBar** just tint the progress color of the rating-bar by your condition no need to set the theme on it

```
ratingbar.setProgressTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorAccent)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ContextThemeWrapper`

```
RatingBar ratingBar = new RatingBar(new ContextThemeWrapper(mContext, R.style.Theme_AppCompat));
```

Comment: and how  to set this for that : android.R.attr.ratingBarStyleIndicator

Comment: Use the overload constructor
`RatingBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes)`

Comment: @BehzadGhadimi this parameter means style reference name in theme.

Comment: It seems it did not get theme :(, not worked for me

Comment: is the theme MyRatingBar contain ratingBarStyleIndicator reference?

Comment: that saved my life, thanks, I made indicator parent of MyRatingBar, thanks

Comment: you can't change resource file at compile time @TangKe